# Why Script error and unable to use google maps in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, google-maps, browser, microsoft-edge

I want to use Microsoft Edge browser to google map and also Microsoft Edge is also up to date. But why is there such a script error.

Thanks

```
 Private Sub btnMap_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMap.Click
        Dim state As String
        Dim city As String
        Dim street As String
        state = txtstate.Text
        city = txtcity.Text
        street = txtstreet.Text
        Dim GetAddress As New StringBuilder
        GetAddress.Append("https://maps.google.com/maps?q=")
        If txtstate.Text <> "" Then
            GetAddress.Append(state + "," & "+")
        End If
        If txtcity.Text <> "" Then
            GetAddress.Append(city + "," & "+")
        End If
        If txtstreet.Text <> "" Then
            GetAddress.Append(street + "," & "+")

        End If
        browser.Navigate(GetAddress.ToString)
    End Sub
```

[error script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyB0Y.png)

Comment: Use [WebView2](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+edge+browser+control&cvid=b33599420df64586a383e99569396bd3&aqs=edge.1.0l8j69i58.8155j0j4&FORM=ANAB01&PC=U531). Also, there's no benefit from using `StringBuilder` when you append concatenated strings. Call `.AppendFormat` instead or `.Append` interpolated `$` strings.

Comment: Are you using WebBrowser Control in this case?

Comment: @KendrickLi , Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that [the WebBrowser Control is a wrapper around IE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), so it is expected that Google Maps will redirect you to the Google Maps support page (because IE has gone out of support), thus triggering the Script Error.

The best solution is to switch to [WebView 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/), which uses Microsoft Edge as the rendering engine. No such Script Error will pop up then.

Answer (score 0):

The script error you are encountering is unrelated to your VB.net code, rather it is an error that is detected in one of the scripts you are trying to load via the web page.

If you prefer, you can disable this warning message by enabling the **ScriptErrorsSuppressed** property:

```
browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

Comment: Your answer code is only to bypass the script error but still does not appear in that browser

Comment: I answered your question regarding the script error. To fix the error you are getting, refer to Kendrick Li's answer.